# XML deserialization Windows 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-runtime

I have problems deserializing an XML file saved to LocalStorage.

I have the following classes, that VS2012 generated automatically:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class plist
    {
        public plistDict dictField;
        public decimal versionField;
        public plistDict dict
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dictField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dictField = value;
            }
        }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public decimal version
        {
            get
            {
                return this.versionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.versionField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class plistDict
    {
        public string keyField;
        public string stringField;
        public string key
        {
            get
            {
                return this.keyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.keyField = value;
            }
        }
        public string @string
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stringField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.stringField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I do this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(plist));
                            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + filename)
                            {
                                plist current = (plist)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                            }
```

And here is the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.ImportTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo, Boolean directReference)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.ModelScope.GetTypeModel(Type type, Boolean directReference)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type type, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
       at App.Controls.App.<>c__DisplayClass6.<<UserControl_Loaded>b__5>d__8.MoveNext() in c:\Users\afomenko\Desktop\App\App\App\Controls\App.xaml.cs:line 165
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Is there anything in the `InnerException` property of the error you get?  I would also set your fields to `private` and only leave the properties public, though I don't think this is the source of your error.